# Mediawiki Scribunto can't split page by slash

Tags: lua, mediawiki, scribunto

I have a Scribunto module that is supposed to format sub pages using more indented bullets:

```
local p = {} --p stands for package

function p.subpage_bullets( frame )
    local page = frame.args.page
    local parts = mw.text.split( page, "/", true )
    return string.rep("*", #parts) .. " " ..  parts[#parts] 
end

return p
```

This works as expected in the debug console.

```
=p.subpage_bullets(mw.getCurrentFrame():newChild{title="whatever",args={["page"]="Foo/Bar"}}) 
** Bar
```

I'm using it from DPL like so:

```
{{#dpl:
format=,{{#invoke:Helpers|subpage_bullets|page=%PAGE%}},<br />
|ordermethod=none
|namespace= {{NAMESPACE}}
}}
```

The result is that the pages are not indented. So a page Foo/Bar returns `* Foo/Bar` instead of the expected `** Bar`.

Why is it not working? I tried replacing `"/"` in the split with `"%2f"`/`"%2F"`, which didn't change the result.

Another related question is that the bullets are rendered as `*` and not interpreted as wikitext so not rendered as an actual bullet.

Comment: Invoking this module on MediaWiki 1.36 with `page=Foo/Bar` gives me the expected `** Bar` (parsed as well). What version are you running? Does it work if you try the invocation outside of DPL?

Comment: @Xxmarijnw Thanks for trying it! I have Mediawiki 1.36, The extension is from https://github.com/Universal-Omega/DynamicPageList3/archive/refs/tags/3.3.7.tar.gz and Scribunto is the one that comes with MW with no additional settings.
It works if I invoke it like so: {{#invoke:Helpers|subpage_bullets|page={{FULLPAGENAME}}}}

Comment: To be more exact, MW is 1.36.2

Comment: @Xxmarijnw, I just realized you may have passed it the Foo/Bar literal. This works for me as well, but is not parsed (I see `**` and not an indented bullet). Which is why I thought there is something funky with what is the value of %PAGE%, but I tried to convert to string (e.g. if it is an object) and it seems like a regular string